# How to convert nested sql query to join?

Tags: sql, join, nested, db2

Please help me rewrite below query using join:-

```
update "+tableName+" set F_RK='T' 
where ISN in ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT B.ISN 
    FROM "+tableName+"_PE_BA AS B,"+regisTableName+" AS C, F0093 AS D  
    WHERE B.F_BB = C.F_AB
    AND C.F_FB = D.F_AB
    AND D.F_OA = 1 
    AND C.F_FC = (SELECT MAX(E.F_FC) FROM "+regisTableName+" AS E WHERE E.F_AB = C.F_AB)) 
and F_RK is null or F_RK=''";
```

Also, I want to optimize the query.

Comment: which database are you uding

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS(MySQL, SQL Server, Orcle, etc) which u r using.

Comment: Can your `tableName` be joined on any of `"tableName" + _PE_BA`, `regisTableName` or `F0093`?

Comment: You should also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Not all DBMS support joins in updates... But almost all support Explicit joins within the nested subquery, so you don't need to use a 15 years out of date bit of SQL

Comment: I am using IBM db2 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimisation, consider a `where exists` (may or may not improve performance). For readability, use explicit joins.

```
Update MyTable
set F_RK = 'T'
where exists
(
select 1
from Table2 B
inner join Table3 C
  on B.F_BB = C.F_AB
inner join Table3 D
  on C.F_FB = D.F_AB
  AND D.F_OA = 1 
where C.F_FC = (SELECT MAX(E.F_FC) FROM Table4 E WHERE E.F_AB = C.F_AB)
)
or F_RK is null 
or F_RK=''
```

Comment: Is is query considering F_RK is null or F_RK=''" part?

Comment: @RiddhiPatil Now it is